# pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_to_group not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, automation, whatsapp

I used `pywhatkit` today. Code below:

```
import pywhatkit as kit

kit.sendwhatmsg_to_group("Group name","Message",hr,min)
```

After opening whatsapp web,it is showing couldn't join the group. Please help me. I am using Vscode in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

"Group name" must be the group ID of the WhatsApp group. The admin has that data.
You can get the data from the link used to become part of the group.

For example, you can see [here](https://chat.whatsapp.com/1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i) that the group ID is the last path on the link `1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i`.

Answer (score 2):

I use this code and works:

```
import pywhatkit
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_to_group("1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i", "Hello world", 17,7)
```

Parameters:

1. Group ID
2. Text you want to send
3. Hour you want message to be sent
4. Minute you want message to be sent

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am use your code .It just open whatsapp only but not send message .Can you assist me  ? . Thank you .